# Sml how to use "nested" structures

Tags: sml, smlnj

How can i define "nested structures" in SML in such a way that i can do something akin to this:

```
structure Why_Does =
  struct
     val seriously = "..."

     Structure This_Not_Work =
       struct
          val hmm = "this confuses me"
       end
  end
```

and then use `Why_Does.This_Not_Work.hmm` ?

I get a `Error: unbound structure: This_Not_Work in path Why_Does.This_Not_Work.hmm` exception

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you've typed "Structure" with a capital S, which is wrong - maybe that's the problem? If I fix that, your code works just fine for me in mosml.

Comment: The misspelling of `structure` is not the problem. I'm running SM/NJ so there might be some difference in how hey handle modules.

Comment: @HenrikSommerland, it works fine in SML/NJ as well. Are you sure that you didn't mistype or misenter something?